# importing vCard file in android via code

Tags: java, android

How to import a vCard file in android via code?

Here's my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile(outputPath+MainActivity.resultUrl)),"text/x-vCard"); 
//Here outputPath is the path of the vCard file and resulturl is 
// the name of the vCard file
startActivity(intent);
```

I am using the above code to import a vcf file, but i am getting an error like `couldn't import vCard -I/O error`

What could be the problem?

Comment: What *exactly* is the value of `outputPath+MainActivity.resultUrl`.

Comment: result.txtresult.txt @CommonsWare

Comment: `results.txtresults.txt` sounds broken. Shouldn't it be `results.txt`?

Comment: Beyond that, is `newFile()` somehow associating this name with a directory? Otherwise, that is not a valid filesystem path.